# scons: *** Two environments with different actions were specified for the same target: sfpseudodepth

Tags: makefile, scons, ubuntu-22.04, class-constructors

I try to install Madagascar on Ubuntu22.04.
My error came after running make install, the error is: `make: *** [Makefile:7: install] Error 2`

I have just used Linux, I tried to find a solution to this problem, but I still don't understand what went wrong, so please help me.

This is the contents of my Sconstruct file:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('../../framework')
import bldutil

progs = '''
integral1 pseudodepth
'''

mpi_progs = '''
mpirtmiso
'''

place = ''

try:  # distributed version
    Import('env root pkgdir bindir')
    env = env.Clone()
except: # local version
    env = bldutil.Debug()
    root = None
    SConscript('../../api/c/SConstruct')

src = Glob('[a-z]*.c')

env.Prepend(CPPPATH=['../../include'],
            LIBPATH=['../../lib'],
            LIBS=[env.get('DYNLIB','')+'rsf'])

mpicc = env.get('MPICC')
for source in src:
    inc = env.RSF_Include(source,prefix='')
    obj = env.StaticObject(source)
    env.Ignore(inc,inc)
    env.Depends(obj,inc)

lapack = env.get('LAPACK')
if lapack:
    if not isinstance(lapack,bool):
        env.Prepend(LIBS=lapack)
    progs += ' pseudodepth'
elif root:
    place += ' pseudodepth'
    for prog in Split('pseudodepth'):
        prog = env.RSF_Place('sf'+prog,None,var='LAPACK',package='lapack')     
        env.Install(bindir,prog)

fftw = env.get('FFTW')
if fftw:
    progs += ' zomiso zomvti'
elif root:
    place += ' zomiso zomvti'
    for prog in Split('zomiso zomvti'):
        prog = env.RSF_Place('sf'+prog,None,var='FFTW',package='fftw')
        env.Install(bindir,prog)

mains = Split(progs)
for prog in mains:
    sources = ['M' + prog]
    bldutil.depends(env,sources,'M'+prog)
    env.StaticObject('M'+prog+'.c')
    prog = env.Program(prog,[x + '.o' for x in sources])
    if root:
        env.Install(bindir,prog)

mpi_mains = Split(mpi_progs)
if mpicc and fftw:
    for prog in mpi_mains:
        sources = ['M' + prog]
        bldutil.depends(env,sources,'M'+prog)
        env.StaticObject('M'+prog+'.c',CC=mpicc)
        prog = env.Program(prog,[x + '.o' for x in sources],CC=mpicc)
        if root:
            env.Install(bindir,prog)
else:
    place += mpi_progs
    for prog in mpi_mains:
        prog = env.RSF_Place('sf'+prog,None,var='MPICC',package='mpi')
        if root:
            env.Install(bindir,prog)


######################################################################
# SELF-DOCUMENTATION
######################################################################
if root:
    user = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
    main = 'sf%s.py' % user
    
    docs = [env.Doc(prog,'M' + prog) for prog in mains+mpi_mains+Split(place)]
    env.Depends(docs,'#/framework/rsf/doc.py')  
    doc = env.RSF_Docmerge(main,docs)
    env.Install(pkgdir,doc)
```

Here is my operation and related information:

```
(base) master@MasterComputer:~/Python/Madagascar/madagascar-4.0$ ./configure --prefix=/home/master/Python/Madagascar
checking for Python ... /home/master/anaconda3/bin/python
checking Python version ... 3.9.13
checking for RSFROOT ... /home/master/Python/Madagascar
checking for SCons ... /home/master/anaconda3/bin/scons
checking SCons version ... v4.4.0.fc8d0ec215ee6cba8bc158ad40c099be0b598297
Running RSFROOT=/home/master/Python/Madagascar /home/master/anaconda3/bin/scons  config ...

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
checking platform ... (cached) linux [ubuntu]
checking for C compiler ... (cached) gcc
checking if gcc works ... yes
checking if gcc accepts '-x c -std=gnu17 -Wall -pedantic' ... yes
checking for ar ... (cached) ar
checking for rpc ... no
checking complex support ... yes
checking for X11 headers ... /usr/include
checking for X11 libraries ... /usr/lib/X11
checking for OpenGL ... yes
checking for sfpen ... (cached) xtpen
checking for ppm ... no

  Optional package: libnetpbm10-dev
checking for tiff ... no

  sfbyte2tif, sftif2byte, and tiffpen will not be built.

  Optional package: libtiff5-dev
checking for GD (PNG) ... no

  gdpen will not be built.
 
  Optional package: libgd-dev
checking for plplot ... no

  Optional package: libplplot-dev
checking for ffmpeg ... no

  Optional package: libavcodec-dev
checking for cairo (PNG) ... no

  Optional package: libcairo2-dev
checking for jpeg ... no

  sfbyte2jpg, sfjpg2byte, and jpegpen will not be built.

  Optional package: libjpeg-dev
checking for BLAS ... no

  Optional package: libblas-dev
checking for LAPACK ... no

  Optional package: liblapack-dev
checking for SWIG ... (cached) no

  Optional package: swig
checking for numpy ... (cached) yes
checking API options ... (cached) []
checking for C++ compiler ... (cached) g++
checking if g++ works ... yes
checking if g++ accepts '-std=gnu++17 -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -Wall -pedantic' ... yes
checking for MPICC ... (cached) /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.1/comm_libs/mpi/bin/mpicc
checking if /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.1/comm_libs/mpi/bin/mpicc works ... no

  Optional package: libopenmpi-dev
checking for MPICXX ... (cached) /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.1/comm_libs/mpi/bin/mpicxx
checking if /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.1/comm_libs/mpi/bin/mpicxx works ... no

  Optional package: libopenmpi-dev
checking for MPIRUN ... (cached) /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.1/comm_libs/mpi/bin/mpirun
checking for Posix threads ... yes
checking for OpenMP ... yes
checking for CUDA ... (cached) /usr/local/cuda
checking if /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.1/compilers/bin/nvcc works ... yes
checking for FFTW ... no

  Optional package: libfftw3-dev
checking for SuiteSparse ... no

  Optional package: libsuitesparse-dev

scons: *** Two environments with different actions were specified for the same target: sfpseudodepth
File "/home/master/Python/Madagascar/madagascar-4.0/build/user/xuxin/SConstruct", line 61, in <module>
```

Then

```
(base) master@MasterComputer:~/Python/Madagascar/madagascar-4.0$ make install
RSFROOT=/home/master/Python/Madagascar PYTHONPATH=/home/master/Python/Madagascar/lib/python3.9/site-packages /home/master/anaconda3/bin/scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: *** Two environments with different actions were specified for the same target: sfpseudodepth
File "/home/master/Python/Madagascar/madagascar-4.0/build/user/xuxin/SConstruct", line 61, in <module>
make: *** [Makefile:7: install] Error 2
```

I tried to change "`configure --prfix=...`" This command, but it seems that my change of address does not work.

Comment: This is super weird.  It looks like an Autotools `configure` script launching SCons, which is already a Frankenstein mashup, With `make` in front, which is putting the cart before the horse with respect to `configure`, and is simply out of place with respect to SCons.

Comment: I see no evidence that you are doing anything inherently wrong. It looks like the SCons build system for this project is buggy.  This should be raised as an issue against the Madagascar project (whatever that is).  In the meantime, it is conceivable that you could work around the issue by making  some of the optional packages available to the build, perhaps LAPACK in particular, but the Madagascar team would be the most appropriate people to look to for help.

Comment: With what's posted here, we don't see rules to build the target it's complaining about, so not much anyone can say. And at a quick glance at the project, it doesn't seem to *directly* access that target. Seems like contacting that project is the best way forward..

Comment: What logic builds `sfpseudodepth` it's likely being called twice with two different Environment()'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, this issue has been solved by the developers in Madagascar.https://github.com/ahay/src/issues/285

Comment: Which would be the first version number without this bug?